# how to share a flutter app with integrated sql db

Tags: sqlite, flutter

i made a flutter app which creates then uses an sqlite db.
To share my app, i used to upload the apk file in google drive, but everytime it is downloaded then installed on a phone, the db is empty.
I want to share the app with the db filled, but i don't know how to do this.
Any help please ?

Comment: Where do you store your db file?

Comment: I don't know, i just use DatabaseHelper to create a sqlite db. I don't know another way to create a db in flutter. But I can change from sqlite to another sgbd if this makes things possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your users run app at first time, their database is empty. Your problem can be solved by two ways:

1. Create entities in database (data that you sharing) at database initialization.
2. Create a backup feature that provides possibility to import database from the user's storage (just replace `db` file in app's internal folder by `db` file from external storage (`Downloads` folder for example)).

Comment: first, thx for ur answer. I made the app for a doctor who will fill the db and then he will share the app with the db with his assistants (by email or google drive). So, the first solution isn't possible. I don't understand how to implement the second one.

Comment: Database storing as a file with `.db` extension in app's internal directory in the user's storage. You can get database file and copy it to any (if your app have storage permission). place on the user's device. Also you can replace existing database by database from Google Drive. For your situation may be simpler to create a JSON file and write/read to/from it?

Comment: I don't know how to use JSON files, but I can learn. Can we fill the JSON file by using a user interface.

Comment: Your user fill a data in UI, app read values from fields and create a JSON structure with it. After that you can save created JSON structure to a file and share this file to Google Drive. On other device you can read a JSON file and parse values to fields in UI.

Comment: If I do so, I'll have to send the apk and the JSON file with the doctor, who will use the app to fill the file, and then he will make the same with his assistants, who will use the app to read the file. I'm right?

Comment: Doctor can install your app once and load different JSON files with a data for a different patients. Assistants also can install your app once and load JSON files that sends from a doctor.